# How to change QR image size?

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I want to know how to change QR code image size? This is my code. It creates QR code but small.

```
    String Cus_Name = (String) cmbCus_NameAdd.getSelectedItem();
    String Cus_Id = lblCus_IDAdd2.getText();
    String Odr_No = lblOrderNoAdd2.getText();
    String Matir = lblMeterialAdd2.getText();
    String amount = txtNoOfProductAdd.getText();
    String date = lblDateAdd2.getText();
    String time = lblTimeAdd2.getText();
    String place = (String) cmbPlaceAdd.getSelectedItem();

    String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    String Details = "Customer Name - " + Cus_Name + "" + newLine + " Customer ID - " + Cus_Id + "" + newLine + " Order No - " + Odr_No + "" + newLine + " Material - " + Matir + "" + newLine + " Amount - " + amount + "" + newLine + " Date - " + date + "" + newLine + " Time - " + time + "" + newLine + " Place - " + place + "";

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = QRCode.from(Details).to(ImageType.JPG).stream(); // this line creates QR code
    File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Pulasthi Dinusha\\Desktop\\MainGui\\lib\\QR_Generator_Libs\\" + Odr_No + ".jpg");
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fos.write(out.toByteArray());
        fos.flush();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(test2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(test2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    ImageIcon iconLogo = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Pulasthi Dinusha\\Desktop\\MainGui\\lib\\QR_Generator_Libs\\" + Odr_No + ".jpg");
    // In init() method write this code
    lblQRcodeAdd.setIcon(iconLogo);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My Solution Of QR Image Resize**

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class QRCodeImageResizer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File folder = new File("/Users/pulasthi/Desktop/images");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        System.out.println("Total No of Files:"+listOfFiles.length);
        Image img = null;
        BufferedImage tempPNG = null;
        BufferedImage tempJPG = null;
        File newFilePNG = null;
        File newFileJPG = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/pulasthi/Desktop/images/"+listOfFiles[i].getName()));
                tempPNG = resizeImage(img, 100, 100);
                tempJPG = resizeImage(img, 100, 100);
                newFilePNG = new File("/Users/pulasthi/Desktop/images/resize/"+listOfFiles[i].getName()+"_New.png");
                newFileJPG = new File("/Users/pulasthi/Desktop/images/resize/"+listOfFiles[i].getName()+"_New.jpg");
                ImageIO.write(tempPNG, "png", newFilePNG);
                ImageIO.write(tempJPG, "jpg", newFileJPG);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Saved");
    }

    /**
     * This function resize the image file and returns the BufferedImage object that can be saved to file system.
     */
    public static BufferedImage resizeImage(final Image image, int width, int height) {
        final BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        final Graphics2D graphics2D = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
        graphics2D.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
        //below three lines are for RenderingHints for better image quality at cost of higher processing time
        graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        graphics2D.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, null);
        graphics2D.dispose();
        return bufferedImage;
    }
}
```